# Segmentation Fault in g++

Tags: c++

I a new to C++. I am implementing Linked List in C++.

```
/*
CTCI: 2.4

Partition a linked list at value x. ALl the noeds less than x comes before
x and all the nodes more than x come after
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;   
};

Node *create_node(int val){
    Node *tmp = new Node();

    if (tmp == NULL){
        cout<<"Memeory allocation failed";
        return 0;
    } else {
        tmp->data = val;
        tmp->next = NULL;
        return tmp;
    }
} 

void createSLL(Node *& head, int d){
    Node *tmp = create_node(d);
    Node *ptr;
    if (head == NULL)
        head = tmp;
    else{
        ptr = head;
        while(ptr->next != NULL)
            ptr = ptr->next;
        ptr->next = tmp;
    }
}

void display(Node *head){
    Node *ptr = head;
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return;
    while(ptr->next != NULL){
        cout<<ptr->data<<"->";
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    cout<<ptr->data<<endl;
}

Node *pivotPartition(Node * head, int data){
    Node *firsthead = NULL;
    Node *secondhead = NULL;
    Node *tmp = head;

    if(tmp == NULL)
        return NULL;

    while(tmp != NULL){
        Node *next = tmp->next;
        if(tmp->data < data){
            tmp->next = firsthead;
            firsthead = tmp;
        }
        else{
            tmp->next = secondhead;
            secondhead = tmp;
        }
        tmp = next;
    }
    if(firsthead == NULL)
        return secondhead;
    else
        tmp = firsthead;
    while(tmp->next != NULL)
        tmp = tmp->next;
    tmp->next = secondhead;
    return firsthead;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   Node *head;
    createSLL(head, 3);createSLL(head, 9);createSLL(head, 7);
    createSLL(head, 1);createSLL(head, 4);createSLL(head, 8);
    display(head);
    Node *p = pivotPartition(head, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

This code gives segmentation fault on g++ but when I run this code on Ideone it works just fine. [See here](https://ideone.com/SNR0BU)

This is happening for many programs.  have latest version of g++ and I am running ubuntu 14.04

EDIT:
My code works until I do not return anything or receive anything from pivotPartition function.
when I change `Node *p = pivotPartition(head, 4);` to `pivotPartition(head, 4);` code works fine.

Comment: What have you done to figure out the problem so far?

Comment: Tried debugging through gdb. I get this `#0  0x000000000040099f in createSLL(Node*&, int) ()
#1  0x0000000000400b41 in main ()` I am stuck here.

Comment: You aren't initializing `head`.

Comment: Node* head has never been initialised

Comment: Node* head = new Node() should work

Comment: I am passing a reference of head. So, it get initialized in createSLL.

Comment: @Death-Stalker It does not get initalized in createSLL, unless it was NULL to start with, which it wasn't.

Comment: try `Node *head;` --> `Node *head = NULL;`

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, got it. New to Statically typed language, thought passing a reference will do the magic. Now it works.

Comment: The `createSLL` function requires `head` to be set to a value because the first thing it does is reads its value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize Node * head with NULL within main.